# What methods are available in the Flower HTTP API?

Tags: celery, flower

I want to use the [Flower](https://github.com/mher/flower) HTTP API to monitor Celery, but I can't seem to find any documentation of available REST methods, other than the few examples on the README.  Can anyone point me in the right direction, or is reading the source code the only option?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All HTTP API methods are documented and available at http://flower.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html

Answer (score 3):

You can check the urls.py for a list of all methods:
https://github.com/mher/flower/blob/master/flower/urls.py